# Is there an equivalent to mod_status for Tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

As the title says, I would like to know if there's something equivalent to Apache's [mod_status](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_status.html) for Tomcat servers.

A few more details:

- Java version: 1.5 (ideally, but I could convinve management to shift to 1.6 if necessary)
- Tomcat version 6.0.16
- Tomcat is running in a production environment, therefore overhead and security should be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

How about [PSI Probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/) ?